# Distribution and expectation value of ceiling function of Poisson

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is Poisson random variable $X$
$$P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!}e^{-\lambda}$$
And define random variable $Z=\lceil \beta X \rceil$  ( $\beta$ is rational number which is less than 1).

How can I find the distribution of $Z$?

And what is expectation value?

Expectation is linear, so is expectation value $\lceil\beta E[X]\rceil$?

Comment: Use the definition of the ceiling function ($\lceil a \rceil = x \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ if $x - 1 < a \leq x$) to compute $P(\lceil \beta X \rceil = x)$.

Comment: Your last sentence is false, as $\lceil\cdot \rceil$ is not linear. Take for instance a r.v. $X$, which is $0$ with probability $1/3$ and $3$ with probability $2/3$, and set $\beta = 1/2$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X]=2$, so $\lceil\beta \mathbb{E}[X] \rceil = 1$. But $\mathbb{E}[\lceil \beta X\rceil] = \frac{2}{3} \left\lceil \frac{3}{2}\right\rceil = \frac{4}{3}.$

Comment: @ClementC., your computation is off. $\mathbb{E}[ \lceil \beta X \rceil ] = \frac{2}{3} \lceil \frac{3}{2} \rceil = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @vonbrand Are you sure? $\frac{3}{2} = 1.5$, so the ceiling of this number is $2$, not $1$.

Comment: @ClementC.. brain glitch.

Comment: No worries... It's the morning :)